# Can I parse and render KML files using the Google Maps IOS SDK

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps

I have an application that uses MapKit on ios to render KML files that are generated from Google Earth. The more complex polygons do not render correctly in ios's MapKit.

I'm wondering if the Google Maps iOS SDK has the ability to parse and render google map or google earth generated KML files? If so if you could point me to an example that would be great.

Answer (score 1):

From this Google Maps API documentation: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/api-picker

KML rendering is currently only available in Javascript API, not in iOS SDK yet.